# hp p2000 iscsi Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, storage-area-network, iscsi

I currently have an HP P2000 SAN with 2 MSA with 4 iSCSI ports each. Only 2 iSCSI ports per MSA were utilized. One going to each of our SAN Switches and furthermore to our hosts. Throughput has been lacking lately and the idea was brought forth to utilize the remaining 2 iSCSI ports per MSA. I have assigned the ports an IP in the SAN Network and added to the appropriate vLAN. As this is new to me, is there anything else that should be done from an OS (win Serv 08 / Hyper-V) perspective to utilize the additional links? i am sure there is more information i need to provide, so ask away and i would be happy to fill in the gaps

Comment: Adding more ports on the SAN won't help if you are maxing the connections on your host. That  aside you need to add more information, such as what type of connections are on the hosts and SAN (1 of 10Gb/s), what MPIO (if any) policy/configuration you are using. Also are you host nics teamed?

Comment: Nor will adding more ports to access your storage help if your SAN disks are already handling the maximum number of IO operations they can.  "Throughput has been lacking lately" strongly implies that performance was acceptable in the past.  What changed?  How are the disks and LUNs configured?

Comment: I assume each host has 2 active connection to SAN. In this case, on each Win 2k8 host you could reconfigure MPIO Round Robin policy utilizing 4 available SAN connections. Check the [guide](http://cscmblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/windows-2012-how-to-configure-multi_13.html)